# Android sms notification issue

Tags: android, notifications, sms

I'm having some trouble with my app. I'm inserting programmatically sms to test into inbox folder, 
but i cannot "simulate" original sms notify. I don't want to make my own, but i want to call the original one. The message is in inbox folder, with status unread.

Otherwise, is possible to refresh "sms inbox", such a way to recognize the unread sms and provide to notify themself?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> I don't want to make my own, but i want to call the original one.

There are thousands of Android device models. These ship with dozens, perhaps hundreds, of default SMS clients. In addition, users can install their own SMS clients.

A few, at most, might provide some sort of documented and supported API by which they would trigger this notification. You will need to contact each SMS client vendor directly and ask them if they offer such a capability.

Moreover, what you are trying to do (modify the SMS inbox) [does not work on Android 4.4+ unless *you are* the user's chosen SMS client](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html), in which case it is your job to show the notification.

> is possible to refresh "sms inbox", such a way to recognize the unread sms and provide to notify themself?

Again, a few SMS clients, at most, might provide some sort of documented and supported API by which they would trigger this notification.